# How to make focus property stay until I click another button

Tags: html, css, button

I'm looking for a way to make the "focus" property stay until I click one of the other buttons.

Normally, focus goes away even if I click anywhere else, but I need it to stay unless I click only one of the other buttons.

Solutions that include JavaScript are accepted as well, but only without using libraries.

```css
button:focus {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<div class="example">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
  <button>button 4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not going to be able to do that with just CSS. You'll need JavaScript.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know! I'll accept solutions for javascript as well.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question to include that stipulation.

Comment: Check my answer I added js code and it's working as you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("button").focusin(function(){
    $('button').css('color',''); // Remove Before set color to selected button
    $(this).css("color", "red"); // Set Color to Selected Button
});
```

```css
button:focus {
  color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="example">
  <button>button 1</button>
  <button>button 2</button>
  <button>button 3</button>
  <button>button 4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Is there a way of doing it without using jQuery?

Comment: @lanWing It's not possible without jquery if you focus after clicking outside you need this.

Comment: Ok, unless I receive other answers this one stays as the best one so far. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: I am assuming you have advanced understanding of REACT in here, if you need more explanation then please comment!

If you are using REACT, then you can do this:

1. map through an array that will create the buttons:

   ```
   const buttonArr = ['button1', 'button2', ... etc]
   ```
2. return the button via MAP method:

   ```
    {buttonArr && buttonArr.map((el, idx) => {return <button {el} /button>})
   ```
3. create state to hold INDEX of selected button:

   ```
   const [indexOfActive, setIndexOfActive] = React.useState(0);
   ```
4. create ONCLICK in the button to set the index of the clicked button:

   ```
   onClick={() => setIndexOfActive(idx)}
   ```
5. create IF condition inside the button IF index of the MAP iteration matches the state index, then apply class

   ```
   <button className={indexOfActive === idx ? "className1" : "className2"}
   ```

Alternatively, you can use React Nav Bar library which will add class ACTIVE to a clicked element, but you will have to set up the React Router infrastructure, which is not worth for small task like this.